doubts about Bulkify code for trigger for notes creating based on user and status of case object
this is the first time writing the trigger and there are two for loops I am using. where after one for loop again I used the next for loop. so while doing bulkify update is there any error that will come? and is this write-away add for loop under another for loop
I like to create a trigger that restricts the user from creating new notes from the case when the logged user is different from the case owner.
I have written some code. but don't know whether it is correct or not or any salesforce govern limit.
Please check whether this code is right or wrong. if wrong please help me with this code.
Code from triiger-
(Trigger.isInsert&&Trigger.isBefore)
{
    Tet_TTNoteTriggerHandler.displayErrorfordifferentUser(Trigger.new);
}

Code from handler -
//to prvent creating new notes when logged-in user is different from case owner and showing error message.
public static Void displayErrorfordifferentUser (List<TT_Note__c> newList) {
    String  errorMessage = system.Label.Tet_ClaimNotesError;
    Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (TT_Note__c note : newList) {
        caseIds.add(note.CaseNumber__c);
        //System.debug('Notecasenumber   '+note.CaseNumber__c);
    }

    //System.debug('caseIds   '+caseIds);
    Id UserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        
    List<Case> ClaimtickectList = new list <Case>([Select Id, OwnerId, Status from Case where Id IN :caseIds and RecordType.Name = 'Claim']);
        
    for (TT_Note__c note : newList) {
        for(case cliamTicket : ClaimtickectList){
            if(note.CaseNumber__c == cliamTicket.Id){
                if(!(UserId == cliamTicket.OwnerId && (cliamTicket.Status <> 'Closed' && cliamTicket.Status <> 'Cancelled'))){
                    note.addError(errorMessage);
                }
            }           
        }          
    }
}


I don't think that this type of code review is on-topic here (and the "fix it for me" part is certainly not). It would be more on topic if you pointed to a single, specific thing/concept that you're unsure of. 95% of "bulkification" is just making sure that you don't have any queries or dml inside of a loop.

Hi @DerekF, Thanks for your comment. I am new to salesforce. this is the first time writing the trigger and there are two for loops I am using. where after one for loop again I used the next for loop. so while doing bulkify update is there any error that will come? and is this write-away add for loop under another for loop

List<Case> ClaimtickectList = new list <Case>([Select Id, OwnerId, Status from Case where Id IN :caseIds and RecordType.Name = 'Claim']);

A query is already a list; there's no need for new List<Case>().

for (TT_Note__c note : newList) {
    for(case cliamTicket : ClaimtickectList){
        if(note.CaseNumber__c == cliamTicket.Id){
            // ...
        }
    }
}

You should never use this design. It is expotentially expensive; if you have a maximum of 200 records in a trigger, this loop requires up to 40,000 iterations in total, which can make it take several seconds instead of a handful of milliseconds.
However, as I've said before, nested for loops are not inherently a Bad Thing. There are times when you will need to use them. For example, processing all of the products for a list of opportunities requires a nested for loop, or processing all of the contacts for some accounts. The trick is to learn to spot this specific pattern, because it is a Bad Thing.
Instead, you use a Map:
Map<Id, Case> claims = new Map<Id, Case>([
  SELECT OwnerId, Status 
  FROM Case 
  WHERE Id = :caseIds AND RecordType.Name = 'Claim'
]);
for (TT_Note__c note : newList) {
  Case claimTicket = claims.get(note.CaseNumber__c);
  if(claimTicket != null && claimTicket.OwnerId != userId && 
      claimTicket.Status != 'Closed' && claimTicket.Status != 'Cancelled'
  ) {
    note.addError(errorMessage);
  }
}

